Merging into protected main branch omitting its latest changes
In my github repo there are two branches:

main which is protected to change only by pull requests.
work branched from main two months ago (from commit A) and has many changes.

How can we create a PR that removes all the commits between A and HEAD of main and uses only the new changes between A and HEAD of work?
A simple PR forces some unrelated changes from main after A into the merge.
I tried branching locally from HEAD of main, then copying locally all the files from HEAD of work, but the results are similar.
I tried using local merge with ours strategy, but when on the github PR the late changes are still there.

Removing commits when the branch is protected and only accepts PR is.... Contradictory.
You could..... Merge main into work using -s ours (which will create a merge commit but the contents is just the way it is in work), then you can create a PR from that point which will get you main just the way work was before we started the process:
git checkout work
git merge -s ours master
# now push and create a PR


You cannot remove commits with a PR. Commits can only be removed by force pushing1. If you truly wish to remove commits from main, you will either need to temporarily remove branch protection, or temporarily grant someone the ability to bypass protection, and then:
git switch main
git reset --hard A
git push --force-with-lease

If you only care about removing the changes in those commits without removing the commits themselves from the history, then a revert will work, either on main or on your work branch after merging main into work. One way to accomplish the same effect as the revert is to use eftshift's answer. If you use that method though, I'd recommend using a special commit message to make it clear that the merge is ignoring the changes, since that would not normally be expected. Perhaps something like "Merge but ignore latest changes from main".

1Another way to accomplish a force push is to delete the branch from the remote, and then re-push a different HEAD. The deletion of the branch is essentially a force push though, and typically requires force push permission as well.
